# PHP Mail with CC

Tags: php

I like to send a contact-form with a php cc-field.

My current code does not work:

```
$email_headers = "From: $vorname <$email>";
$email_headers .= "Cc: <$email>";
```

Comment: You're missing the carriage returns. There are loads of examples in the comments of the [mail() documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate your headers lines with a carriage return `\r\n`:

```
$email_headers = "From: $vorname <$email>" . "\r\n";
$email_headers .= "Cc: <$email>";
```

According the [PHP mail documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code :

```
$email_headers= 'From: Birthday Reminder <$email>' . "\r\n";
$email_headers .= 'Cc: $email' . "\r\n";
```

Hope this will work for you. You can check more from here too  :http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php